# Scrollbar getting stuck with jQuery show & hide

Tags: jquery, scroll, hide, show

I'm using jQuery to show and hide various divs to paginate content. However, immediately after selecting an option that shows or hides the divs (for example, page 1, 2 or 3) and scrolls erratically up and down rather than let me scroll down the page. I have no idea at all what could be doing this, and having searched Stack Overflow and Google it doesn't appear to be a problem that anyone else has faced. Does anyone have advice on what could be causing this problem and how to rectify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you do not want the page to jump to the top? If so, it is happening because your `<a>` tags have `href="#"`. This is normal behaviour for browsers and you can test this on any site. Just scroll down the page, add a hash to the end of the URL press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the browser will move to the top of the page.

You are using jQuery to bind a function to the click event on the `<a>` tags which will first execute the function and then continue to follow the `href`. To prevent this continuation you can either `return false;` from the function or use in-built jQuery functions [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) and [`stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to prevent the *default* behaviour and stop the event propagating - see [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

So change your code to:

```
$("div.pages a.page1").click(function() {
    $("div.pd-item#tethco, div.pd-item#novi, div.pd-item#inna").show();
    $("div.pd-item:not(#tethco, #novi, #inna)").hide();
    return false;
});
```

And also do the same for the `a.page2` and `a.page3` bound functions and the page will no longer jump.

Comment: Thanks very much, that did it. There was one other factor causing the problem - the smooth scrolling function I'm using was detecting the href="#" and trying to animate the links; I fixed it by adding :not([href$=#]) to the selector.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(".datepicker").focus(function () {
    parent = $(this);


    $("#ui-datepicker-div").position({
        my: 'left center',
        at: 'right center',
        of: parent
    });
});
```